# ignorar errores de sintaxis en javascript

Tags: javascript, sintaxis

Actualmente tengo un código que me funciona en todos los navegadores excepto en internet explorer. Quisiera encontrar una manera de obviar este código cuando estoy en internet explorer, es decir que no se me muestren los errores. lo que pretendo es encerrar mi código en una especie de if o try catch y que no se ejecute. qué puedo hacer?

obtengo este error:
`SCRIPT1028: Se esperaba un identificador, una cadena o un número`

```js
var nombresColumnas=["data0","data1","data2","data3"];

var data= {
 [nombresColumnas[0]]: '#33E789',   //error here..!
 [nombresColumnas[1]]: '#00CCFF',
 [nombresColumnas[2]]: '#FFC33E',
 [nombresColumnas[3]]: '#384858'
}
    
console.log(data)
```

Comment: ¿No sería más fácil reescribir el código para hacerlo compatible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que estás utilizando se llama `Computed Property Names`

```
const myKey = 'Dynamic'
let obj = { [myKey]: 'myValue' }
```

Puedes comprobar su compatibilidad en distintos [navegadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility).

Como verás, en IE **`NO`**`está soportado`.

No puedes ignorar los errores en tiempo de ejecución, lo más sencillo sería reescribir el código como comenta Pablo o utilizar herramientas que lo hagan por ti a la hora de desarrollar como [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Tengo una función que verifica el navegador, me parece que te puede servir así ejecutar determinado script dependiendo del navegador;

```js
function Verificar_navegador() {
         var detectarNavegador = window.navigator.userAgent;
         var chrome = /Chrome/;
         var firefox = /Firefox/;
         var opera = /OPR/;
         var edge = /Edge/;
         var safari = /Safari/;
         var navegador;
         if (chrome.test(detectarNavegador) && !(opera.test(detectarNavegador)) && !(edge.test(detectarNavegador))) {
          navegador = 'Google Chrome';
         } else if (firefox.test(detectarNavegador)) {
          navegador = 'Firefox Mozilla';
         } else if (safari.test(detectarNavegador) && !(chrome.test(detectarNavegador))) {
          navegador = 'Apple Safari';
         } else if (opera.test(detectarNavegador)) {
          navegador = 'Opera';
         } else if (edge.test(detectarNavegador)) {
          navegador = 'Microsoft Edge';
         } else {
          navegador = 'Desconocido';
         }
         
        return navegador;
        }
        
   console.log(Verificar_navegador());
```

**Extra:**

Puede verificar si el usuario no tiene javascript habilitado, de no tenerlo habilitado puedes utilizar lo siguiente para re-dirigirlo a algún lugar que quieras(Esto va en el `head` html, no en tu javascript);

```
<noscript>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=index_incompatible.html">
</noscript>
```

Comment: gracias por qué pones 2 veces las validaicones de los navegadores? mira el segundo if. no es redundante?

Comment: @yavg tienes razón, gracias he corregido mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Como te dicen otros usuarios, sería mejor que hicieras código compatible con todos los navegadores sin tener código específico para alguno de ellos (lo cual es un síntoma de problemas en el código).

Pero... si quieres tener algo específico para IE, puedes aplicar una solución parecida a lo que se sugiere en la [solución de SpiderCode en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19999868/3695983), que aplicado a tu código se vería así:

```js
var nombresColumnas=["data0","data1","data2","data3"];
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ")

if (msie < 0) {
  var data= {
    [nombresColumnas[0]]: '#33E789',   //error here..!
    [nombresColumnas[1]]: '#00CCFF',
    [nombresColumnas[2]]: '#FFC33E',
    [nombresColumnas[3]]: '#384858'
  }
}    
console.log(data)
```

Comment: gracias por responder.. pero igual se mostraria el error en internet explorer...

Comment: @yavg He hecho pruebas en IE y el código se salta correctamente, mostrando `undefined` en la consola (porque la variable `data`no se asignó). ¿Qué error recibes? ¿el mismo de antes en el mismo sitio? ¿es alguna versión de IE en particular?